# Weird Outlook Behavior; Creating its own file folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook is doing a very strange thing. It has created a folder on its own (which, whenever I completely delete, comes back, with a different name). Mail that goes into this folder will not go to any other folder unless I forward it. If I move the email or create a rule to always move mail from particular senders to the Inbox, it moves for a while, but then goes  back into the created folder. The first one was called "junk" but it was in addition to my normal junk email folder. When I forwarded all the messages (some were junk, but most were not) and totally deleted that folder, a new one, called "unwanted" appeared that acted the same way. It seems that once one email goes into this folder, then any email from that person also goes into the folder. I have discussed this with the tech person at work. There is no evidence of virus or any other identifiable reason for this to happen. We have searched the Internet and not found anything like this either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem on a Samsung s5.
It appears as if an update changed the name of the spam folder that the built in email app on the Samsung phones changed from "Junk" to "Unwanted".

Per the link that user367162 provided the fix is to go into the email app on the phone and remove the blocked addresses from the filter.

Go into the E-Mail app

Press the Menu Key

Select Settings

Select General Settings

Select Spam addresses

Remove any addresses that should not be in there. For example if you see *@gmail.com the asterisk is commanding all new emails from gmail to go to the Unwanted folder. At some point when you reported an email as spam you may have chosen to block the Domain instead of the address accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d00cab48-d386-4e84-b4c2-d872d77bd26e/outlook-creates-extra-folder-called-junk-in-mailbox?forum=outlook

Check out the info on this forum.. It sounds very similar and may be your answer.

Comment: This is a link only answer.  As links can change, please include an explanation of what you suggest

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you sync Outlook with other IMAP (or similar format) accounts such as iCloud mail or Gmail.  This folder exists on the account that is synced with Outlook, so if you delete it locally in Outlook, it will re-appear the next time Outlook syncs with whatever remote mail service you are using.

By default, in Outlook you have a Junk folder, but let say you want to sync Outlook with iCloud, which also has its own Junk folder, or Gmail which has its own Spam folder.  It is not possible to delete these folders from iCloud or Gmail, because they are permanent folders, so they will always appear when synced with Outlook.

There are possible workaround that I have used in the past (such as Gmail having the option to "Always hide" certain folders -- one check box for the web interface, and another checkbox for IMAP).

You may also want to look into your IMAP root (I believe is what it's called) in your Outlook settings, which will affect the way your remote IMAP folders are displayed in Outlook.

I always used to set my clients up with the root as [Gmail] (or something like that), which would make everything appear more organized and apart from the native Outlook folders so that they could keep track of what was remote and what was local.

I hope this helps!